# Как инжектить класс из одного бандла внутри сервиса другого бандла?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

У меня существует два кастомных бандла симфони, оба подключаются к основному проекту, и как проект, так и один из бандлов используют методы  второго бандла. Первый бандл это мессенджер, второй - логгер, соответственно методы логгера используются в мессенджере. При попытке в сервисе мессенджера сделать следующее:

`public function __construct(string $apiUrl, LogService $logger)`

получаю ошибку

`Too few arguments to function Acme\NotifierBundle\Service\NotificationService::__construct(), 1 passed in /var/cache/dev/Container51Q3Syr/getAppControllerService.php on line 26 and exactly 2 expected`

Если правильно понимаю, первый аргумент приходит нормально из .yaml, а второй нет.

Оба бандла конфигурируются своими ямлами. Как здесь правильно поступить, что необходимо сделать, чтобы не делать `new LogService::class`, а именно передавать LogService как аргумент в __construct()?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: для LogService в файле сервисов приложения задать алиас(эдакий мост)

```yaml
#config/services.yaml
services:
   
   my.logger: '@неймспейс\LogService'
```

а в конфигурации бандла, в сервисе где этот логгер инжектится явно указать:

```yaml
#bundle/Resources/config/services.yaml

services:
   
   first_bundle_service:
       class: Неймспейс\Класс
       arguments:
          $apiUrl: 'https://url...'
          $logger: '@my.logger'
```

PS: ну и желательно не использовать в бандле такую жесткую зависимость от LoggerService, а сделать так, например, чтобы LoggerService реализовывал бы Psr\Log\LoggerInterface (psr-3) и в зависимостях указывать этот интерфейс.